# Is there a way to get information on deleted record when calling IndexedDB's objectStore.delete?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer-10, indexeddb

When I execute a `delete()` from an objectStore, the event appears to have no information relating to the deleted record. It does not give me the key back, or even have anything confirming the delete (other than calling the success callback). The `event.target.result` is `undefined`.

Is there a way for it to give me some information?

**console.dir( event )**

```
Event
    bubbles: false
    cancelBubble: false
    cancelable: false
    clipboardData: undefined
    currentTarget: null
    defaultPrevented: false
    eventPhase: 0
    returnValue: true
    srcElement: IDBRequest
    target: IDBRequest
        error: null
        onerror: function () { [native code] }
        onsuccess: function deleteNext(event)
        readyState: "done"
        result: undefined
        source: IDBObjectStore
        transaction: IDBTransaction
        webkitErrorMessage: undefined
        __proto__: IDBRequest
    timeStamp: 1371417349691
    type: "success"
    __proto__: Event
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the point ...

If you enter the onsuccess callback off the delete operation, it was successful. In all othercases you will enter the onerror callback.

Why would you like to get back?

If you do a delete statement in a SQL database, you also don't get back anything...

Comment: except the spec docs state that a success function does not imply the records were in fact deleted: "it's not possible to know if some records were actually deleted“

Comment: You can be sure that the delete operation was successfull, but not that any records are deleted. Meaning of you try to delete an object or a range that doesn't have any records the delete will be successfull as it should. SQL just works the same. If you want to know the number of items that will be deleted, you can do a count first and delete afterwards. Hope this awnsers the question

Comment: I understand that but all the SQL databases I've used offer a way to grab that info. e.g. MySQl: `mysql_affected_rows` tells you if any rows were actually deleted. There's nothing in IndexedDB to do the same, and no way to query for the count to tell you this (because it wouldn't be atomic. In between your call to "delete" and "count", another DB operation could run that affects the count). But in MySQL, you could run `mysql_affected_rows` within the same synchronous transaction (and have that table locked).

Comment: I don't think that is an issue. I think indexeddb uses locks on object store level. That way you can't open concurrent readwrite transactions for 1 objectstore. I'll try to confirm that asap.

Comment: I believe it does use those locks, but I *think* by the time you reach the success callback, it's been released. So test it where other callbacks try to make a change after your `onsuccess` function is executing and before you call `count()`. Please let me know what you find.

Comment: What I ment was making the count and delete call in the same transaction. This way you can't have issues

Answer (score 0):

Pardon my language, but WTF? Apparently, there is no (at least standard) way to get any information about the deletion operation. In fact, you **cannot even know if it was successful**!

**From Mozilla:**

> As per spec the result of the Object Store Deletion Operation algorithm is undefined, so it's **not possible to know if some records were actually deleted** by looking at the request result.

**From the spec:** http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#object-store-deletion-operation

> The result of this algorithm is undefined.

This seems to be a **major** fail. How can a database not even acknowledge success or failure of an operation?!

Comment: You are correct, it is a bit of a wtf moment. I suppose one reason would be related to the very design of no-sql oriented persistence tools. It helps to learn about concepts like 'eventual consistency' and 'opportunistic locking'.